# onCreateViewHolder not called in PagedListAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, android-recyclerview

I have **PagedListAdapater**:

```
class TrackedActivityAdapter constructor(diffUtilCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<TrackedActivity>) :
    PagedListAdapter<TrackedActivity, TrackedActivityAdapter.TrackedActivityHolder>(diffUtilCallback) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TrackedActivityHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val view = DataBindingUtil.inflate<ActivityItemBinding>(inflater, R.layout.activity_item, parent, false)
        return TrackedActivityHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TrackedActivityHolder, position: Int) {
        getItem(position)?.let { holder.bind(it) }
    }

    class TrackedActivityHolder(var binding: ActivityItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(trackedActivity: TrackedActivity) {
            binding.activity = trackedActivity
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }

    }
}
```

And fragment in which this adapter created:

```
class HistoryFragment : DaggerFragment() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<HistoryFragmentViewBinding>(
            inflater,
            R.layout.history_fragment_view,
            container,
            false
        )
        val historyViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(HistoryViewModel::class.java)
        val adapter = TrackedActivityAdapter(TrackedActivity.DIFF_CALLBACK)
        binding.trackedActivityRv.adapter = adapter
        binding.trackedActivityRv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(binding.root.context)
        historyViewModel.getTrackedActivities().observe(this,
            Observer<PagedList<TrackedActivity>> { t ->
                adapter.submitList(t)
            })
        binding.executePendingBindings()
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

After the adapter.submitList (t) method has been called. Nothing happens, and the onCreateViewHolder and onBindViewHolder methods are not called, please tell me there could be a reason, I just can't understand (

Comment: I had a similar issue - turns out I'd done `adapter.setHasStableIds(true)` and then forgotten to implement `adapter#getItemId`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `HistoryFragmentViewBinding.inflate(inflater)` instead of `DataBindingUtil.inflate()`?

I had the same problem and got stuck for days. Turns out I just returned the wrong view at the end. It wasn't like yours, but probably worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It is only one line different from you, and the code is exactly the same. In my case

```
recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true)
```

Was added. When I removed this, onCreateViewHolder() was called.
So, I don't know exactly which part of your code is the problem, but try to handle this part as well.

```
val adapter = TrackedActivityAdapter(TrackedActivity.DIFF_CALLBACK)
binding.trackedActivityRv.adapter = adapter
binding.trackedActivityRv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(binding.root.context)
binding.executePendingBindings()
```